# How do I successfully install windmill?

Tags: windmill

After following 
    https://github.com/windmill/windmill/wiki/installing

I installed and added python 2.7 to my path I received a 404 when I ran ez_setup.py.

```
C:\windmill\windmill-windmill-4304ee7>python ez_setup.py
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c9-py
2.7.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ez_setup.py", line 270, in <module>
 main(sys.argv[1:])
File "ez_setup.py", line 202, in main
 egg = download_setuptools(version, delay=0)
File "ez_setup.py", line 150, in download_setuptools
 src = urllib2.urlopen(url)
File "C:\recsolu\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
 return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\recsolu\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
 response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\recsolu\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "C:\recsolu\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 438, in error
 return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\recsolu\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
 result = func(*args)
File "C:\recsolu\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
 raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

C:\windmill\windmill-windmill-4304ee7>
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if you follow the instructions nearly to the letter, it should work.  This include saving what looks to be an outdated ez_setup.py file.

I'm running now.